# Haskell lexer problems

Tags: haskell, types, lexer

I'm writing a lexer in haskell. Here's the code:

```
lexer :: String -> [Token]
lexer s
    | s =~ whitespace :: Bool =
        let token = s =~ whitespace :: String in
            lex (drop (length token) s)
    | s =~ number :: Bool =
        let token = s =~ number :: String in
            Val (read token) : lex (drop (length token) s)
    | s =~ operator :: Bool =
        let token = s =~ operator :: String in
            Oper token : lex (drop (length token) s)
    | otherwise = error "unrecognized character"
    where
        whitespace = "^[ \t\n]"
        number = "^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"
        operator = "^[+-*/()]"

data Token = Val Int | Oper String
```

There are two problems I'm having. One, the number regex `"^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"` throws this error:

```
lexical error in string/character literal at character '['
```

And when I comment out the line containing it and the part of the function that uses it, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Token'
           against inferred type `(String, String)'
      Expected type: [Token]
      Inferred type: [(String, String)]
    In the expression: lex (drop (length token) s)
    In the expression:
        let token = s =~ whitespace :: String
        in lex (drop (length token) s)
```

I have no idea why I'm getting either of these errors. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backslashes are used as escape characters in string literals, like in `"\n"` for a string containing a newline. If you want a literal backslash you need to escape it as `"\\"`.
That's the problem in the regex `"^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"`, the Haskell parser tries to interpret `"\."` as a normal string escape and chokes on it (probably because there is no such escape). If you write the regex as `"^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?"` the error goes away.

The reason for the type problem is that you call [`lex`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:lex) from the standard Prelude in `lex (drop (length token) s)`, which has type `String -> [(String, String)]`. Probably you wanted to do a recursive call to your own function `lexer` instead...

Answer (score 2):

Also, note that `"^[0-9]*(\\.[0-9]+)?"` matches an empty string or numbers like .12 (instead of 0.12), which you probably don't want. It is a serious problem, because it would cause your function to call itself infinitely. To fix that, change * to +.